# Continuously write to subprocess using popen in C++

Tags: c++, ipc, popen

I need to open a subprocess using popen, the process will continuously ask for user input... The main process need to send that data over the pipe.

This is my first attempt:

```
FILE *in;
char buff[1024];

if(!(in = popen("cd FIX/fix2/src; java -cp .:./* com.fix.bot", "w"))){
    return 1;
}

while(1){
    char buffer[] = { 'x' };
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), in);

    cout << "Wrote!" << endl;
    usleep(1000000);
}
```

However the data is not sent! I need to close the pipe with pclose() so that the data is written to the process. How can I make sure to write the data without having to close the pipe everytime?

Comment: is it possible that your app is looking for input terminated with a \n?  Because you are not sending a LF right now...

Comment: Don't forget to check the result of `fwrite()` I don't think it guarantees to write everything you request. Usually it does but you need to validate.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to call `fflush(in)` to make sure that the buffered data is actually written to the stream.

Also check that `java -cp .:./*` in the command isn't expanding to an invalid classpath. I think that'll end up expanding to several arguments if there's more than one file in the current directory, and not actual classpath entries.

Comment: It still doesn't flush... I still need to close the pipe even with fflush(). What could be the problem?

Comment: I updated the answer, and I think it may also be that the classpath is getting set wrong. Try doing `echo java -cp .:./*` to see if it looks legitimate.

Comment: I'll make sure to check the command to open the java process... But so far it seems to be working fine. The data is written to the pipe when I close it and the Java process responds accordingly. But I need to make sure the data is flushed....

Comment: Another note from the man page: "Since the standard input of a command opened for reading shares its seek offset with the process that called popen(), if the original process has done a buffered read, the command's input position may not be as expected.  Similarly, the output from a command opened for writing may become intermingled with that of the original process.  The latter can be avoided by calling fflush(3) before popen()."

Comment: @LuisCruz:  Then your problem is in the reader, not the writer. `fflush` will definitely write the byte(s) to the pipe. The only thing closing the pipe does is send EOF. You need to show your reading side source code and change this to a Java question.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   FILE *in;
   char buff[1024];

   if(!(in = popen("./2.sh", "w"))){
       return 1;
   }

   while(1) {
      char buffer[] = "xx\n";
      fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), in);
      fflush(in);
      std::cout << "Wrote!" << std::endl;
      usleep(1000000);
   }
}
```

where 2.sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh

read INP
echo 'read: ' $INP
```

So I am really suspecting that the problem is missing \n.